# How to create a transformed table on Microsoft Access Form

Tags: ms-access, transpose

In Microsoft Access I need to display a table with the headers down the left side, instead of being across the top.  So far I've found a lot of people asking this sort of thing, but no good solutions.  I have found that Microsoft supplies a VBA function to do this:
Method 2 at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/202176

That function creates another table in the access database.  I will modify that so that instead of creating a new table, it either prints the table to the form calling the function or returns a table, depending on what Access is able to do.

Can the Record Source property be set to a function?  I haven't seen a way to do this so far. If that's not possible, in the Form_Load() event, what commands could I use to manually create a datasheet (providing the rows and columns in transformed order).

Thank you for your advice.

Comment: How many records so you want to turn into columns?

Comment: Infinite.  I'm using a form, not a report, so I can freeze the first column as users scroll.

Comment: well the max number of columns you can pivot is 255 (probably because the max number of columns in a table is 255), so infinite will not work. Even if you output this to excel the max number of columns in excel is ~16k.

Comment: If you are trying to manually create a datasheet with transposed data you are in for a lot of work. The max number of controls you can ever have on a form is [754](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/access-2007-specifications-HA010030739.aspx). I'd suggest representing your data in a more traditional manner.

Comment: Even if I have to limit the number of records to 255, that would still be helpful.  I'm surprised it is so complicated to display a table left to right instead of top to bottom.  If I wanted to write a VBA function manually to do this, what method prints to the screen?

Comment: You can't even do this in a pivot query, you need to read every record in a recordset into a control on your form. That being said, if you make a form to hold 255 column of data you are only going to get ~3 rows on it. Because the max number of controls on a form is 754 you can't even fit a full three rows. If you want to make these data editable, it's going to be another big headache. Since you can't waste controls on screen storing primary keys you'll need to store them in a dictionary or have some way of linking back to the original recordset.

Comment: There is no "prints to screen" method. You can set the value of controls. You should edit your question to explain specifically what is tripping you up about the code you have written. You have asked a very broad and potentially advanced question.

Comment: OK, I get that this can't be done in Access. Thanks